# Want to insert data into my Local database via a button on the web, but there seems to be an issue with the connection

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

I created a local database inside visual studio it self (1st time that I've done like that)

I got the following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-50MFBOD\Hugo; Initial Catalog=Database_AvaliacaoConnectionString1; Integrated Security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

When I click the insert button, it doesn't insert the data into my GridView and it pops up this error:
[image]

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error ... **in the question itself.***

Comment: @Plutonix You're right.

Comment: Is the web application running on a server that has network access to "DESKTOP-50MFBOD"?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes

Comment: That connection string is obviously wrong. Use a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Things you should check:

[image]

Open SSMS and login with following details:

*ServerName*: DESKTOP-50MFBOD\Hugo

*Authentication*: WindowsAithentication

If you are not able to login then probably:

- your ServerName is wrong OR
- Maybe some problem with your TCP/IP connection from SQL server.

If ServerName is wrong, try to use correct name. You can expand the ServerName dropdown during login to SSMS to find correct instance name.

If problem with TCP/IP you can refer following link to see how to fix it. 
https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/hibernate/solving-sql-server-connection-problem/

Comment: Yes, for some reason the error is different now, it says it can't log in

Comment: If you are not able to login from SSMS with WindowsAuth try to login with default sa login. It the dosen’t work, maybe your sql server version is expired. Check windows eventLogs to know more about error.